# doubt while solving the differentail equation $y'=y^2+t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was dealing with a multiple choice question:

Let $y(t)$ be a solution to the differential equation $y'=y^2+t$, then $y(t)$ is differentiable

(a) once but not twice

(b) twice but not 3 times

(c) 3 times but not 4 times

(d) infinitely many times

I thought lets first obtain the solution and then I can think about its differentiability.

I tried:

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}\frac{dy}{dx}&=y^2+t\\\frac{dy}{dt}-t&=y^2\\\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{t}{y^2}&=1\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

Here I tried to take $y^{-1}=v$, but it didn't worked well as I got the equation as $-\frac{dv}{dt}-v^2t=1$, which is not a linear differential equation.

How should I solve this equation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to solve the equation. If $y$ is a differentiable function satisfying the equation $y'=y^{2}+t$ then a simple induction argument shows that $y$ is infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Riccati equation. It does not have a symbolic solution in elementary expressions. You can transform it into an Airy equation and express $y$ as quotient containing Airy functions.
$$
y=-\frac{u'}{u}\implies 0=u''+tu
$$

If the right side is $C^k$, then the solution is $C^{k+1}$, this is also true for $k=\infty$. Polynomial functions are smooth.